# R, data.table, utf-8 %in% vs == problems

Tags: r, encoding, data.table, match

I have strange behaviour of data.table and %in% operator.
I am loading data.table with Russian letters in utf-8 header.

```
d = fread(filename, sep="\t", encoding="UTF-8", verbose=TRUE)
bar=names(d)
bar

 [1] "Дата, Время"      "Состояние"        "Ia, A"            "Ib, A"            "Ic, A"           
 [6] "Дисб.I"           "акт.P,кВт"        "P, кВА"           "cos"              "Загр., %"        
[11] "Uвх.AB,В"         "Uвх.BC,В"         "Uвх.CA,В"         "Дисб. U, %"       "R, кОм"          
[16] "F Турб.вращ.,Гц"  "Приток,куб.м/cут" "Отбор,куб.м/cут"  "P, ат."           "Расход, куб.м/c" 
[21] "Tдвиг, °C"        "Tжид, °C"         "Pвыкид, ат."      "Tвыкид, °C"       "Вибр X/Y, м/с2"  
[26] "Вибр Z, м/с2"     "Pвыс.р, ат."      "Iутеч, мA"        "Tобм, °C"         "Акт.энерг,кВт"   
[31] "Реакт.энерг,кВАр" "Вход1,ед."        "Вход2,ед."        "Вход3,ед."        "Вход4,ед."       
[36] "Вход5,ед."        "Вход6,ед."        "Вход7,ед."        "Вход8,ед."        "Статусн.сообщ."
```

I have one of values hardcoded in code

```
foo="Uвх.AB,В"
```

And trying to do the following

```
if (foo %in bar) { ... }
```

to the surprise

```
foo %in% bar

[1] FALSE
```

but

```
foo==bar

 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[17] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[33] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

notice the TRUE on 11th position, the reason is in encoding

```
Encoding(foo)

[1] "UTF-8"

Encoding(bar)

 [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[10] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[19] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[28] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[37] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" “unknown"
```

On data.table behalf it is just a bit strange because I’ve asked encoding="UTF-8” on fread. 
On the other hand %in% aka **match** behaviour difference with == is also very strange.

I sense the wrongness of the universe, could somebody explain me why is %in% acts in so strange way with encodings and what is correct way of using it?

Comment: It would be better to include your sample data in a more [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Ideally something that doesn't rely on using `fread` from a file that we don't have access to. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have an issue with `fread()` but not with `data.table` in general?

Comment: I see something similar with the name constructor in `data.frame()`. Bad result: `"Uвх.AB,В" == names(data.frame("Uвх.AB,В" = 1))` vs good result: `"Uвх.AB,В" == names(setNames(data.frame(1),"Uвх.AB,В"))`. It's probably because `fread` uses `make.names` unless you set `check.names = FALSE`.

Comment: give `read.csv2` a shot, colleague had encoding issues that were resolved with it, maybe it works for you

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back ago: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633211/data-table-logical-comparison-and-encoding-bugs-errors-in-non-english-enviromen/40906765#40906765

Check if your problem is fixed with the new dt version 1.9.8